# python default configuration reuse of variables

Tags: python

```
class DefaultConfig(object):
    class S3(object):
        DATA_ROOT = 's3://%(bucket_name)s/NAS'
        DATA_LOCATION = '{}/%(instrument_id)s/%(run_id)s'.format(DefaultConfig.S3.DATA_ROOT)
```

The code above gives me the following error.

```
      File "./s3Utils.py", line 5, in <module>
    from InfraConfig import InfraConfig as IC
  File "/opt/src/datasource/src/main/python/util/InfraConfig.py", line 4, in <module>
    class DefaultConfig(object):
  File "/opt/src/datasource/src/main/python/util/InfraConfig.py", line 6, in DefaultConfig
    class S3(object):
  File "/opt/src/datasource/src/main/python/util/InfraConfig.py", line 14, in S3
    DATA_LOCATION = '{}/%(instrument_id)s/%(run_id)s'.format(DefaultConfig.S3.DATA_ROOT)
NameError: name 'DefaultConfig' is not defined
```

Why is it unable to find DefaultConfig.S3.DATA_ROOT
Also, this is my attempt at writing structured configuration with reuse of values of DefaultConfig. Is there a way to do this without writing a yml file?

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski: This actually is an MCVE.

Comment: @user2357112 yep, I misread and misinterpreted the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use it without any prefixes:

```
class DefaultConfig(object):
  class S3(object):
    DATA_ROOT = 's3://%(bucket_name)s/NAS'
    DATA_LOCATION = '{}/%(instrument_id)s/%(run_id)s'.format(DATA_ROOT)

 print DefaultConfig.S3.DATA_LOCATION
```

returns:

```
> s3://%(bucket_name)s/NAS/%(instrument_id)s/%(run_id)s
```

Answer (score 2):

It is unable to find the `DefaultConfing` because `DefaultConfig` is not defined at the moment `S3` is created.

Remember that class are objects. Because there are objects, that means they need to be instantiate. Python instantiate a class at the end of its definition, and therefore register it in the globals. Because the class definition is not finished, you can't use the `DefaultConfig` name.